# Datepicker div opens inside form and that is why not visible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Image shows that when i click on date it opens inside form

[image]

```
  <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Start Date</label>

                    <div class="input-group date">

                        <datetimepicker
                                ng-click="setStartDateSlider($index)"
                                hour-step="hourStep"
                                minute-step="minuteStep"
                                ng-model="projectData.project_start_date"
                                show-meridian="showMeridian"
                                date-popup="{{format}}"
                                date-format="MM-dd-yyyy"
                                date-options="dateOptions"
                                date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                                datepicker-append-to-body="false"
                                readonly-date="false"
                                disabled-date="false"
                                hidden-time="true"
                                hidden-date="false"
                                name="datetimepicker"
                                show-spinners="true"
                                readonly-time="false"
                                date-opened="dateOpened"
                                show-button-bar="true"
                                placeholder="Start Date"
                                is-open="showdp"
                        <!--style="position: fixed;width:90px;z-index: 1000000" -->
                        >
                    <!-- Use date-ng-click="open($event, opened)" to override date ng-click -->
                        </datetimepicker>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" ng-click="showcalendar()"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am using wizard

Style 
     .wizard,
     .tabcontrol
     {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
     }

```
.wizard > .content
{
background: #eee;
display: block;
margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
min-height: 120px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: auto;

-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
 }

.tabcontrol > .content
{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 35em;
overflow: hidden;
border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Note: i found that if i remove overflow:hidden then it works good but then in mobile device it is not working.

Comment: Does it work on mobile devices with overflow: hidden, just not desktop? Or are you unable to view it correctly on either?

Comment: If i remove Overflow:hidden from every where, the datepicker will work. I mean the div will be visible properly.But the whole wizard will broken in to mobile device.In short nothing will be visible

Comment: is your datepicker inside content class?
does changing (only) it's overflow work?

Comment: Yes my datepicker is inside the content class

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with z-index property of the datepicker